# How to return an XML string as an action result in MVC

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to return XML from a controller's action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

I'm able to return JSON and partial views (html) as a valid ActionResult, but how would one return an XML string?

Comment: Use the XmlResult from [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com) on Codeplex. Also this seems to be a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You could use `return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml");` to return a built XML string from an action.

Comment: If you're working with Linq to XML, creating a string form of the document is wasteful -- it's [better to work with streams](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12718046/24874).

Answer (score 7):

For JSON/XML I have written an [XML/JSON Action Filter](http://aleembawany.com/2009/03/27/aspnet-mvc-create-easy-rest-api-with-json-and-xml/) that makes it very easy to tackle without handling special cases in your action handler (which is what you seem to be doing).

Comment: For anyone reading this post - definately check out his filter... it works well. +1 to aleemb for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is by using XDocument:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

public XDocument ExportXml()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

    return XDocument.Parse("<xml>...");
}
```

Comment: Some experimentation in MVC 4 (and possibly earlier versions) suggests that the MIME type returned here is `text/html`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're building the XML using Linq-to-XML then [check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718046/24874). It allows you to write code like this:

```
public ActionResult MyXmlAction()
{
    var xml = new XDocument(
        new XElement("root",
            new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
            new XElement("child", "Hello World!")));

    return new XmlActionResult(xml);
}
```