# XmlDocument object to view asp.net

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, xmldocument

I just started programming in visual studio Mvc3 for a scoolproject but i cant find a way to give the output of my xml by passing in from the controller to a view.

I made a XmlDocument object and i actually have no idea how to show this. What do i have to return in my controller? one important thing is that i dont want to save the xml files i generate and wanna show.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [How to return an XML string as an action result in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878695/how-to-return-an-xml-string-as-an-action-result-in-mvc). You should be able to get a string representation of your `XmlDocument` using `ToString()` or `OuterXml`