# How do I get MVC to return a Context type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I have the following code I wrote in Asp.NET and I am trying to convert it to MVC, but not sure how I do this within an Action

```
HttpContext context;
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename));

context.Response.WriteFile(filename);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = filename
    };
    Response.SuppressContent = true;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return this.File(filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

So you have a server side script (`PDF.axd`) which generates the PDF file. You don't have the pdf file stored on your file system. In this case you will need to first fetch the pdf and then stream it to the client:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    byte[] pdfBuffer = null;
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var url = string.Format("PDF.axd?file={0}.pdf", voucherDetail.Guid);
        pdfBuffer = client.DownloadData(url);
    }

    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = "file.pdf"
    };
    Response.SuppressContent = true;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(pdfBuffer, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf); 
}
```

The usefulness of this controller action is doubtful as you already have a script that does the job.

Comment: This looks correct, but I'm getting "is not a valid virtual path." even though the file and the URL are correct

Comment: On which line do you get this exception? Is `filename` an absolute path?

Comment: Here is the line that is generating the filename.

            string filename = (string.Format("PDF.axd?file={0}.pdf", voucherDetail.Guid));

I have also tried it using the full URL with HTML:\\ but get the same response

Comment: placing the filename in the URL of IE works fine and a PDF gets displayed

Comment: You are confusing `a filename` and an `url address`. Please see my update.

Comment: Got it, it was the full path on the server I had to give, all working now  :-)

Comment: string filename = Server.MapPath(string.Format("..\\..\\app_data\\GiftVouchers\\{0}.pdf", voucherDetail.Guid));

Comment: Thanks for the update, this is working like a dream on my development machine, but for some reason on the live box, IIS 6 it take about 20 seconds to bring up the save as box on all browsers, it seems to be taking its time on return File(pdfBuffer, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);  any ideas?

Comment: How did you determine that it is exactly this line that takes 20 seconds?

Comment: I watch the browser, anyhow I found the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928494/mvc-action-taking-a-long-time-to-return/1928702#1928702

Answer (score 0):

You meant 'Content' and not 'Context' type, yes?

Maybe this SO post will help:
[ASP.NET MVC and text/xml content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971806/asp-net-mvc-and-text-xml-content-type)