# How to change returned ContentType in ASP.NET MVC controller (ActionResult)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have ASP.NET MVC controller named dictionary with method ControlsLangJsFile.
Method returns view of users control (ASCX) which contain JavaScript variables.

When i call the method it returns variables with parsed strings, but Content Type is html/text. It should be: **application/x-javascript**

```
public ActionResult ControlsLangJsFile()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Dictionary/ControlsLangJsFile.ascx",);
    }
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Users control doesn't accept ContentType="text/xml"

Solution:

```
public ActionResult ControlsLangJsFile()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        return View("~/Views/Dictionary/ControlsLangJsFile.ascx");
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Razor views (not sure about other view engines).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930411/5496) for the solution:

Comment: I'm using Razor / MVC 4 and this works fine in the controller (which is where I'd rather place this as I don't even want a view if I'm returning file-types, such as PDF).

Answer (score 20):

I had this same question while building a razor view with JS in it and attempted to use @jmav's solution:

```
public ActionResult Paths()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"; //this has no effect
    return View();
}
```

That doesn't work when you are returning a View().  It seems that the view rendering sets the content type itself despite what is assigned in the controller method.

Instead, make the assignment in the view code itself:

```
// this lives in viewname.cshtml/vbhtml
@{
    this.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
}
// script stuff...
```

Comment: Setting `Response.ContentType` in the Controller action worked for me in MVC 3.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, just change the content type accordingly:

[ASP.NET MVC and text/xml content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971806/asp-net-mvc-and-text-xml-content-type)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
return Json(new
{
      uCode = SysContext.CurrentUserCode,
      uPwd = SysContext.CurrentUserPwd,
      rMe = SysContext.RememberMe
}, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```