# Change the media type of a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, media-type

For reasons I really don't want to go into (it makes me sad), I am trying to generate dynamic javascript in a MVC5 partial view.  I will be using model data to create a bunch custom javascript functions.  This is to support legacy apps on another platform, so I really don't have many options here for rearchitecting this.

How can I change the media type of the partial view to `application/javascript`?  Do I need to write my own `JavaScriptPartialView` class?  I would have expected the media type to be a property of the `PartialView` class, but it doesn't seem to be.

```
    [Route("~/api/legacy/{id:int}.js?lang={lang?}")]
    protected async Task<PartialViewResult> GetLegacyScript(int id, string lang)
    {
        var model = await _legacyService.GetModel(id.ToString(), lang);
        var pvw = PartialView(model);
        // ??? do what to make this application/javascript?
    }
```

Comment: You mean changing the Response.ContentType? Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439355/how-to-change-returned-contenttype-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-actionresult

Comment: hmm... I had assumed that was encapsulated in the `ActionResult`... that may have been silly of me.