# Stop .Net from changing Content-Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-type

I am developing a MVC application that is accessed by mobile browsers.

Unfortunately, .Net has a tendency to change the content-type from text/html to text/vnd.wap.wml for several older mobile phones.

I know I can create an ActionFilter that overrides this behaviour and forces content-tpe text/html, or I can include the Content-Type in the <%@ Page ... %> directive.

But is there an easier way to stop .Net from changing content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Could use this approach [Return XML from a controller's action in as an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

or this [ASP.NET MVC and text/xml content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971806/asp-net-mvc-and-text-xml-content-type)