# How to upload a file through jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how would I do this with like jQuery ajax. Right now I have a jQuery ui dialog box popup and it has an html input file on it.

Now when the user clicks import I want to do an ajax post to the server with jQuery.

I am not sure how to pass the file in though to my action view.

Right now I have it doing a full post back so I have this

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{%>
    <br />
    <p><input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="23 accept="text/calendar"></p><br />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>        

<% } %>
```

Then in my controller

```
  public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

So I am not sure how to pass in an HttpPostedFileBase with jQuery and how to set `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in jQuery.

**Edit**

Ok well the jQuery form plugin seems to be the way to go.

```
$('#frm_ImportCalendar').livequery(function()
{
    var options = {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
    };

    $(this).ajaxForm(options);
});
```

I was wondering why my json was not working but someone mentioned you can't use it just as is. I am checking out the other link where someone was able to use json.

I am not sure though why in Lck used .submit before the ajax submit method.

**Edit**

How could I change the file upload json result to return my dictionary array?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        result.Add("Msg", "Success!!");
        result.Add("Body", calendarBody);

// how can I change this?
    return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format("{0} uploaded successfully.", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)) } };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the jQuery Form Plugin, you can accomplish an async file upload. Check-out the following link,

jQuery Form Plugin - Code Samples - File Uploads
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dominic, use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/). The form you already built should already work correctly. Just add an ID to identify it:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "asyncForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and use jQuery Form to post the data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#asyncForm').submit(function(){
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSubmit: function(){
                //update GUI to signal upload
            }
            data: { additional = 'value' },
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(xml){
                //handle successful upload
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that the return dataType in forms that upload files *cannot* be JSON. Use XML or HTML as response in your controller's method.

Comment: I was just coming here to ask why it will not return JSON lol. I did something similar but Id id not specify .submit. See edit for what I have so far.

Comment: Javascript cannot accept JSON as data format for requests that uploaded a file for security reasons (it's documented on the jQuery Form webpage). I suggest you use XML which is _almost_ as simple to use as JSON with jQuery... or perhaps values in plain text separated by newlines.
I used .ajaxSubmit explicitly because I took the example from some code of my own project where I do some more stuff with the form. Should be practically equivalent to your code anyway.

Comment: Well how would this XML look like. I posted my Dictionary Collection that I convert to a Json result how can I convert it to XML.

Comment: You can take the XmlResult class from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905
That should also work for the dictionary in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload a file via AJAX using the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) and a custom JsonResult class as described [here](http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/).

Use this to return something like your Dictionary

```
return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { Msg = "Success!!", Body = calendarBody } };
```

and to get your message in the callback function

```
success: function(result) {
  $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
  $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
  alert(result.Msg);
}
```

Comment: What is     $.growlUI(null, result.message);? I am not sure what growlUI is and if that is something I need. Also do I have to put iframe to true?

Comment: Also what is the jason key and value in this? Is it Data or Message?

See edit.

Comment: Yes, iframe needs to be true.  $.growlUI is not necessary, its just a special animated notification.

Comment: i am getting a jquery error: $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm is not a function?