# MVCContrib XmlResult not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I have the current controller code :

```
    public ActionResult BodyDay(int id, int year)
    {
        var repo = new Repo();
        return new  XmlResult(repo.getBodyDay(id, year));
    }
```

It used to return xml now all I get returned is

```
    MvcContrib.ActionResults.XmlResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the raw code from the MVCContrib source from this question primarily so I could debug it

[Return XML from a controller's action in as an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

and it worked like a dream so i moved on to the next problem