# Render XML document (obtained through ajax call) to a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, xslt

Hi I'm looking for a way to render an XML document, that I retrieve using ajax, to a new browser window.

I am using JQuery's ajax() function to post JSON data to an MVC controller. The controller returns XML as a string.

I am using window.open() to create a new window in javascript and set the documents content by calling.

```
newwindow.document.clear();
newwindow.document.            
newwindow.document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
newwindow.document.close();
```

(Where jqXHR.responseText is the XML returned from the ajax() call.)

The new window opens as expected and if I view source on the page I see my XML. BUT (you knew one was coming) nothing appears in the browser window. Obviously if I save the page source to disk and open the output is rendered as expected.

Can anyone suggest a solution? 
Just to re-iterate my main goal is to render an XML document (obtained through ajax call) to a new window.

I should also add that I would like to see the output transformed by an XSLT. My XML has this processing instruction.
Many Thanks

**Edit**--------------------------- THE SOLUTION I WENT WITH -------------------------

Thanks for everyone's comments and suggestions.

The solution that I ended up going with was to have a form with target="_blank" I then wrote the JSON to the form as a hidden field, and posted it to my controller which returned the XML (constructed from the JSON). When the XML was returned from the response the browser marked it up as expected. I guess this is not an answer to the original question. But Gabby has a solution below.

Comment: Do you want to see the raw XML in the window, or are you expecting also than an XSLT transformation will be done to show the actual XML document contents in "human friendly" readable form?

Comment: I would like to see the XSLT transformation appplied

Comment: Not about XSLT itself but cross browser invocation of XSLT processor. Retagging.

Comment: I had similar issue to solve and have posted what I did here.  
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc/19036811#19036811>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will work only in ***FireFox*** and ***Opera***, but i think is worth mentioning ..

```
window.open('data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent( jqXHR.responseText ) );
```

should work with chrome as well but it seems to treat `window.open` differently than a usual URL.. if you just type the resulting url in chrome it works there as well..

---

**Update** *This works with all browsers !*

The thing is that javascript has the ability to tranform xml using xslt.
But not automatically, so we need to find the XML file for the reference to the XSLT file and load that as well. Then we can do the transformation in javascript and pass the resulting html to the new window.

Naturally IE handles thing differently than the rest.

```
$.get('xml-file-here.xml',
   function(xmlData){
                  var xml = xmlData;

                  //extract the stylesheet so we can load it manually
                  var stylesheet;
                   for (var i=0;i<xml.childNodes.length;i++){
                       if ( xml.childNodes[i].nodeName =='xml-stylesheet' )
                       {
                        stylesheet = xml.childNodes[i].data;
                       }
                   }
                  var items = stylesheet.split('=');
                  var xsltFile = items[items.length-1].replace(/"/g,'');

                  //fetch xslt manually
                  $.get( xsltFile, function(xsltData){
                      var xslt = xsltData;
                      var transformed;

                      if (! window['XSLTProcessor'])
                        {
                            // Trasformation for IE
                            transformed = xml.transformNode(xslt);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Transformation for non-IE
                            var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
                            processor.importStylesheet(xslt);
                            var xmldom = processor.transformToDocument(xml);
                            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                            var transformed = serializer.serializeToString(xmldom.documentElement);
                        }

                      var newwindow = window.open();
                      newwindow.document.open();
                      newwindow.document.write(transformed);
                      newwindow.document.close();
                  });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful.. unfortunately i need it to work in IE :O . worth a point though I reckon.,

Comment: @Nixon, do you have multiple xslt's linked or just one ?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something different (see edit above) but your approach answered the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set popup to be `Content-type: text/xml` and ofc start popup with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Then you should be able to read it in almost any browser. Chrome does not style XML without addons.

Answer (score -1):

You might lose a buzzword, but why dont you just open a window that points to the controller's URL?

Comment: Becuase I need to post JSON data from the current page and I want the result to open in a new window

Answer (score -1):

Write the XML into a textarea. Style the textarea using CSS.

Comment: Can you provide some details about how exactly you'd style the contents of a `<textarea>`?

Comment: That won't be suitable for this situation. I have a quite a hefty XSLT that needs to be applied to the raw XML.

Answer (score -1):

Browser renders html. IE and some others open the xml file with formatting, but that's not the default behaviour of browsers - so you should not rely on it. Better solution for me is to suggest to download file, and the user will decide whenever he wants to save the file or open it.
But in case you don't want file download, than you have to generate html from your xml. That's the case when you should make some formatting, add css styles for it to be more user friendly and readable. And to achieve this, the best is to use [Xsl Transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to generate your output html from xml. That would be the most elegant way to generate html directly from xml. But in case you also don't want this, and you really dont care about user experience, you could use some text element (p, span, etc) and write xml not directly into new window, but in this element's text. That way your xml will be displayed as is

Comment: The XML has a processing instruction that links it to an XSLT