# Set page title at Chrome on windows.open when 'about.blank' is not applicable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-chrome

I need to show xml string in new window at Chrome. And also I want to set a title for window.
I found [Render XML document (obtained through ajax call) to a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581592/render-xml-document-obtained-through-ajax-call-to-a-new-window) solution for that. But I have no idea how to set a title for window. If there are any solutions for this? Basically here is a new window creation code part:

```
var newWindow = window.open('data:text/xml; charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(document));
```

Comment: I believe you can not do it if you use a `data` URL

Comment: Any suggestions to not use data URL? 
To use some sort of custom formatters/highlighters for xml and go with 
html type?