# In javascript, how do I replace the full contents of a window with XML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I've been trying to pass some xml contents to a new browser window using the following technique:

```
    var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    newWindow.document.clear();
    newWindow.document.open();
    newWindow.document.write(xmlString);
    newWindow.document.close();
```

However, the xml gets placed inside `<body></body>` tags in the new window.

How can I make my xml doc represent the FULL contents of the window (no `<html></html>` tag)?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581592/render-xml-document-obtained-through-ajax-call-to-a-new-window)

Comment: @SterlingArcher Perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/1sh9tyq9/ (don't forget to allow popups)

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Thanks, I had seen that question, however, it only becomes relevant after I figure out how to make the `<html></html>` tags go away.  It's step #2 once I get the answer to this question. ;)

Comment: @blex - Perfect!  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Troy Nah, that's a duplicate question. My JS Fiddle just uses the technique used in Sterling Archer's link. But if someone else wants to, I won't stop them ;)

Comment: That's Duchess to you, blex.

Comment: @blex - Sure enough.  I had missed it in that post (the answer in case anyone else needs it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581592/#answer-5582205). Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work if you have very large xml strings.

Answer (score -1):

Before writing to the document, you need to remove some elements. I would do the following:

```
//The following performed on the new document you are creating

var tagsToDestroy = newWindow.document.querySelector('html');
newWindow.document.removeChild(tagsToDestroy);

//Then write your content and do whatever else
```

This will clear the html tags, which are the parent node of the body tags, and anything that is a child/grandchild/and so on...

As an aside, I would avoid naming your variables with the keyword "new" in them.