# XML Serialize all properties as CDATA for one class (via IXmlSerializable?)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization

I have an ugly requirement, for all properties of a child class "job", to serialize to XML wrapped in CDATA tags. Here's the spec:
http://www.indeed.com/intl/en/xmlinfo.html

All the answers I find suggest an approach that is suitable for one or two properties, not a whole class. For example: [How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

One of the comments in that article suggests implementing IXmlSerializable on an individual class. Sounds like it may be a better approach, since every property on my job class needs CDATA wrappers, and I don't have this requirement anywhere else. However, it would be even better if there was a per-property member to override on the serializer that I could take advantage of when I do this.

**Any ideas on how to get the CDATA implementation down from 200 lines of code to 10?** It strikes me how simple this would be if not for the CDATA requirement:

```
public class job {
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int referencenumber { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string salary { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string experience { get; set; }

    public job(DataModel.PostedJob postedJob, UrlHelper urlHelper) {
        country = "US";
        category = "contract, project, consulting";
        title = postedJob.Title;
        date = postedJob.PostedOn;
        referencenumber = postedJob.Id;
        url = urlHelper.Action(MVC.SearchJobs.Index(postedJob.Id));
        company = postedJob.Company;
        city = postedJob.City;
        state = postedJob.State;
        postalcode = postedJob.PostalCode;
        description = postedJob.Description;
        experience = postedJob.MinYears.ToString() + "+ years";
    }

    public job() { }
}
```

EDIT: Note that I'm currently serializing this using MvcContrib "XmlResult" code snippet shown here: [Return XML from a controller's action in as an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc) ... The non-traditional case on the property names themselves reflect the XML schema required by the specification linked above. I thought that since view-model properties are typically tightly-coupled to the consumer it was appropriate, but feel free to correct me.

Comment: Side note: Since all the answers I find are 2-3 years old, I also wonder if there's a newer serializer that will magically solve this for me.

Comment: Are all your properties *always* "simple" types (`string`, `DateTime`, `int` etc)? (And are you able to change your names so that they follow .NET naming conventions?)

Comment: Hey Jon. Nice to hear from you. Yes re: simple types, the class you see is the actual view-model/DTO I've implemented, and since it's based on the external spec for a popular service I don't expect it to change soon. Also, I can certainly name the properties to follow the .NET conventions, but I thought it might be clearer to leave the serialization attributes off this class. I do see your point, and a developer has no reason to expect such a dependency anyway.

Comment: I edited above regarding the non-traditional case on the property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is simple, you can write your own serializer using LINQ to XML.

Here's a *very* unpolished version... you'd need to make it cover all the types you need, and also consider how to represent null references if necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { 
            Name = "Jon", 
            Value = 5,
            When = DateTime.Now
        };

        XElement element = Serialize("Foo", foo);
        Console.WriteLine(element);
        Foo bar = Deserialize<Foo>(element);
        Console.WriteLine("Deserialized values:");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
                          bar.Name, bar.Value, bar.When);
    }

    static XElement Serialize(XName elementName,
                              object value)
    {
        return new XElement(elementName,
          value.GetType()
               .GetProperties()
               .Select(p => new XElement
                   (p.Name, ConvertValue(p.GetValue(value, null)))));

    }

    static XCData ConvertValue(object value)
    {
        // This is a bit odd. It takes advantage of LINQ
        // to XML being nice with XElement, but not for
        // XCData
        XElement tmp = new XElement("ignored", value);
        return new XCData(tmp.Value);
    }

    static T Deserialize<T>(XElement element) where T : new()
    {
        T ret = new T();
        foreach (var sub in element.Elements())
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(sub.Name.LocalName);
            SetProperty(property, sub, ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static void SetProperty(PropertyInfo property,
                            XElement element,
                            object target)
    {
        // This is somewhat annoying. There should be a better
        // way...
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        object value;
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            value = (string) element;
        } 
        else if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            value = (int) element;
        }
        else if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            value = (DateTime) element;
        }
        // ...
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't convert " + type);
        }
        property.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: very clever, I would not have thought of it... hold on, still processing