# ExtJs4 Generating an Excel file from javascript in IE gets me:"the data area passed to a system call is too small"

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I've implemented this UX for ExtJs 4 (it generates an Excel file from an ExtJs 4 grid or store)

http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/generate-an-excel-file-from-an-ext-js-4-grid/#comment-982

and it works perfectly in Chrome, however I keep getting this error  " the data area passed to a system call is too small" in any version of IE

Here is the fragment of code that seems to be the problem, the full code is in the link above.

```
    var el = Ext.DomHelper.append(gridEl, {
        tag: "a",
        download: title + "-" + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d Hi') + '.xls',
        //download: 'descarga.xls',
        href: location
    });

    el.click();    //this line seems to be causing the error

    Ext.fly(el).destroy();   
}
```

I know there is downlodify and other options (like server side generating) but they are not an option at this point for me.

Is there any chance I can make this UX work in IE?

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thank you.

Comment: Look here for a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839882/open-html-page-in-excel-via-javascript

Comment: Well I guess I 'll have to send my grid data to the server and try to just return it like "application/msexcel" if that doesn't work I'll have to actually use POI, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the listed method will not work well with IE because IE has a limit of 2083 characters. If you debug the code in this fiddle `https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17j` you'll notice that the location variable is well over 5000 characters and also fails in IE. I'm assuming the issue is the same if you debug your code as well.