# How Asp Mvc choose appropriate ActionResult when action return arbitrary type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Documentation about ActionResult tells that it's possible to return any object from actionmethod and framework select right descender of ActionResult to execute it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx

> You can create action methods that return an object of any type, such as a string, an integer, or a Boolean value. These return types are wrapped in an appropriate ActionResult type before they are rendered to the response stream.

Question is how all that's possible and what the rules of selecting one.

More than, why following code does not cause compile error.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return new MyClass(); //not inherited from ActionResult
}
```

I've tried to find answer digging in Asp Mvc source code hoping to find implicity convertion operator declaring cast from object to ActionResult but I failed.

Maybe someone was luckier and can explain what's happening under the hood.

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.  Is this something in a very new version of MVC?

Comment: @David I use net4.5.1 and asp mvc 5.
I updated my post providing it with reference to msdn.
Did you try to return simple build-in type like string, int and etc?

Comment: I've tried that as well, yes.  But as expected I still see compile-time errors when trying to return anything which isn't an `ActionResult`.  (Which is exactly what I'd suspect.  There's nothing special about a `Controller` class, it's as statically typed as anything else in C#.)  I also don't see any examples of what you're describing on that MSDN article.  Are you *sure* that code is actually compiling for you?  What is the definition of `MyClass`?

Comment: the appropriate type for user-defined content such as this would be `ContentResult`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Question is how all that's possible and what the rules of selecting one.

It's not, you should probably hit F5/F6 (compile/rebuild).

> More than, why following code does not cause compile error.

[The following code will never compile.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sTUHd9).

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  return new MyClass(); //not inherited from ActionResult
}
```

Exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'HelloWorldMvcApp.MyClass' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

You need to read this again:

> ***You can create action methods*** that **return an object of any type**, such as a string, an integer, or a Boolean value. These return types are wrapped in an appropriate ActionResult type before they are rendered to the response stream.

It's not stating that the MVC framework will automatically wrap it for you, it's stating *you can return any object* within a wrapped ActionResult which is what all ActionResult return types do.  It is definitely poorly worded and MVC doesn't do anything *magical* about allowing methods to return a type that doesn't match it's signature (currently).

You can create you own action result, for example an [XmlResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

You can return the JSON object instead of ActionResult for example.

You are missing the point made in next statement. These return types are **wrapped in an appropriate ActionResult type** before they are rendered to the response stream.

```
public JsonResult GetProductDataJson()
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> data = GetData();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

JsonResult is of type ActionResult so you can return that type from Controller.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that

> These return types are wrapped in an appropriate ActionResult type
>   before they are rendered to the response stream.

So you cannot directly return an object into view. It should be wrapped inside either View(), Json() or any other Helper methods.

See link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.100).aspx

If you want to create **your own** ActionResult, create a class that inherits from ActionResult class.

Links

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/533932/Custom-ASP-NET-MVC-ActionResults
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dbd951/how-to-create-custom-actionresult-method-in-Asp-Net-mvc4/

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says you can return any type from an action method. You need to declare the method appropriately so it compiles:

```
public MyClass MyAction()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

You could declare your method as returning `object` and it would still be a valid action method which the MVC framework will happily call.

When you return something which cannot be cast to an `ActionResult` it is converted to a `String` (if not null) and set as the `Content` on a `ContentResult`; The `String` representation of your return value is sent straight to the client. The `CreateActionResult` method of the `ControllerActionInvoker` class handles this:

```
protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
{
    if (actionReturnValue == null)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    ActionResult actionResult = (actionReturnValue as ActionResult) ??
                                new ContentResult { Content = Convert.ToString(actionReturnValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
    return actionResult;
}
```

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs

It is possible to override this behaviour (which is what I was trying to find out how to do when I came across this question) by creating a class which extends `ControllerActionInvoker` and implements your desired behaviour. Then either override the `CreateActionInvoker` method in your controller or assign the ActionInvoker property:

```
public class MyActionInvoker: ControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
    {
        // Your behaviour
    }
}

public class MyController: Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        ActionInvoker = new MyActionInvoker();
    }

    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        return new MyActionInvoker();
    }
}
```