# Create custom xml (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have method to get all values from database

Here is code

```
public IQueryable<TimeTable> GetTimeTables()
    {
        return db.TimeTables;
    }
```

Here is model of TimeTable

```
public partial class TimeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string INN { get; set; }
    public string StartDay { get; set; }
    public string StartPause { get; set; }
    public string EndDay { get; set; }
    public string EndPause { get; set; }
}
```

I need to generate xml from values like this

```
<data>
<worker id="000000000000">
    <start>2016-08-08T08:00:00</start>
    <pause>2016-08-08T13:15:49</pause>
    <continue>2016-08-08T13:15:49</continue>
    <end>2016-08-08T13:15:49</end>
</worker>
<worker id="000000000001">
    <start>2016-08-08T08:00:00</start>
    <pause>2016-08-08T13:15:49</pause>
    <continue>2016-08-08T13:15:49</continue>
    <end>2016-08-08T13:15:49</end>
</worker>
```

Where `id` is INN, `start` is StartDay, `pause` is StartPause, `continue` is EndPause, `end` is EndDay.

How I can do this?

Comment: return on action@alex

Comment: How about create your own method to generate XDocument with requred fields?
I understood, that's a problem using standart [Serializable()]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return XML from a controller's action in as an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-as-an-actionresult)

Comment: If you are using SQL Server as the db engine, you can easily format the XML using the FOR XML and just return the string in your controller https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight-forward, so I'm not sure where exactly you're running into issues. Essentially, you just need to build an `XDocument` like:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("data",
        timeTables.Select(w =>
            new XElement("worker",
                new XAttribute("id", w.INN),
                new XElement("start", w.StartDay),
                new XElement("pause", w.StartPause),
                new XElement("continue", w.EndPause),
                new XElement("end", w.EndDay)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then, you just return this as a `ContentResult` with a mime type:

```
return Content(xdoc.ToString(), "application/xml", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I have code like this

https://pastebin.com/DtB2m0Cq

But I have errors

like this http://imgur.com/a/711bj

Comment: Well of course. That's going to return a `ContentResult` (derived from `ActionResult`), whereas the method you stuck that into returns `IQueryable<TimeTable>`. This code should be in your *action*. The `timeTables` variable would be the result of `GetTimeTables()`, and then the return would be for the action method. Alternatively, you could move the XML creation logic into your `GetTimeTables()` method, but you should then return either `XDocument` or `string` from that method. The `return Content` bit would still be part of your action.