# Return XML from MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Whats the best way to return XML data from an MVC controller?
I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
return new XmlResult(s);
```

Comment: have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134905/return-xml-from-a-controllers-action-in-as-an-actionresult This might give you a better picture.

Answer (score 6):

```
return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        string xmlData="<xml ?>.....";
        return Content(xmlData, "text/xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
   }
```

to return a built XML string from an action.